# Using the webView method, "loadRequest", do I need to worry about threading? (iphone sdk question)

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiwebview

Lets suppose I am creating an application for the iphone with a webView down at the bottom of the window (the other part of the screen has a button and the user can interact with it).

I don't want the webView to stop the user from interacting with the other part of the UI when the webView loads a new url. From my limited testing through the iphone simulator, I haven't been able to determine IF it already behaves this way.  Most of my web sites load pretty fast.

I seem to be able to load new requests and click the ui button while that happens.

So, again, do I need to worry about threading in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not.  The iPhone threads a great deal of the UI components behavior, or schedules them for you in the main run loop in such a way that you rarely need to be concerned, the UI elements will be available for user interaction.